# Unable to add marker in Google Maps Api v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

Since yesterday I'm trying to add marker in Google Maps Api v3 . I read the documentation and all. Here's my code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var map;
  function initialize() {

    var mapOptions = {

      center: new google.maps.LatLng(28.63, 77.21),
      zoom: 8,
  disableDefaultUI: false,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      };
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
        mapOptions);


  }
 // google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

  function getFillingDetails(){
    var vehicleId = $('#selectVehicle option:selected').val();
    $.getJSON('getFillingDetails.php', {id : vehicleId}, function(data){
  var lat = [];
  var lon = [];
  var price = [];
  $.each(data, function(key, value){
    lat.push(value.latitude);
    lon.push(value.longitude);
    price.push(value.price);
    });
  });

  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(23.72,77.10);

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(23.72, 72.100),
            map: map,
        });

  }
</script>
```

Everything looks fine to me. The `initialize()` function is called after `onload` of `body` tag.
And `getFillingDetails()` function is called when I click a button.
But still I'm getting no success.

Comment: Remove comma (,) here map: map, . This will work :)

Comment: It is still not working

Comment: sorry for the silly stuffs..  It worked. Silly me..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a syntax error at:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(23.72, 72.100),
    map: map, <--- get rid of this comma
});
```

next time you should look in the developer console for any errors.

Comment: It still not working. Do I need to call `marker.setMap(map);` after the marker code. ?

Answer (score 1):

```
// To add the marker to the map, call setMap();
marker.setMap(map);
```

source : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers